# Rselenium close other window

Tags: rselenium

When I click a input button.
It show another window.

My code like this.
Click and show other window. (the window names windowB)

```
OpenMEMO <- remDr$findElement(using='id', value='form1:searchListTable')
OpenMEMO$clickElement()
```

After doing something, I want to close windowB.

But I don't know how can I do.

I try to use

```
#retrieve the current window handle
currWindow <-  remDr$getCurrentWindowHandle()

#retrieve the list of window handles used in the session (I have 2 windows)
windows <- remDr$getWindowHandles()

#change focus to another window (windows[[2]] is windowB)
remDr$switchToWindow(windows[[2]])

#close the current window
remDr$closeWindow()
```

I run remDr$closeWindow().
But it closed the original window. (Actually, I want to close windowB)

Maybe I misunderstood the usage of the code.

Please give me some suggestions.

Thanks.

*Because it's intranet, I cannot provide a website link.*

Comment: very strange... I try to use Chrome. It works... I do not know why.

Comment: This issue is discussed here: https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/143. "This issue is due to changes in the underlying API of the driver (geckodriver) which firefox uses."